# My external drive used to be auto-mounted with a certain name, and now it's auto-mounted with another name making links not working anymore

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, thunar

I use Xubuntu as my primary OS (just updated from Focal to Groovy to Hirsute, but the problem I'm going to describe popped up just before the update).

I have a 4Tb external storage that I use everyday since my internal hard disk is quite tiny.

This has been used to be mounted as `/media/dario/Elements` whenever I clicked on it in Thunar, but from a couple of days, it's mounted as `/media/dario/Elements1` and that `1` makes all the software I use (like Thundebird or Transimission) unable to find references to past documents.

Now I can work around by mounting it by command line, which is what I'm currently doing, or I can even manually set up all my software again to look for `Elements1`, but there must be a way to make it mounted as `Elements` automatically by GUI, isn't it? Can you help me?

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 2):

After 5 minutes I found the solution (since I wrote that I was mounting it by CLI, but I lied: I just was intending to do that).

There was a root-owned read-only directory called `/media/dario/Elements`, probably due to a system crash I had, that I removed with `sudo rm -rf` and everything came back to normal (i.e., now Thunar properly mounts my hard disk in `/media/dario/Elements` instead of `/media/dario/Elements1`). Hope this helped some other newbie.

Comment: I was about to answer you the same ;) You explained very well: this can indeed result from an improper system shutdown or a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the drive mount path by adding a line to your `/etc/fstab`
file.

First check the UUID of your external drive by typing: `blkid`

Then open your fstab file and add a line with this content:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxx  /media/dario/Elements       auto    auto,users   0   0
```

You may experiment with different options that suit your needs. This way, you have more control on how the system mounts the external drive.

To apply these changes immediately you can run `sudo mount -a` or reboot.